# Evenly fit ListViews and a Button into a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to fit two Listviews (+two Textviews) and a Button evenly into a LinearLayout. The final result should look something like this:

[image]

The Listviews can contain any number of items (from empty to requiring to scroll), however the button must be always visible. A lot of answers here suggest to use `layout_weight` along with `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_width="fill_parent"`, however this results in the Listviews taking up all available space and pushing the button out of the screen. I assume the parameters for the button are wrong, but I can't figure out which of them. At least the TextViews are working, since they are positioned correctly in every case.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
              android:gravity="center"
              android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="left"/>

    <ListView
            android:layout_height="0dp"                
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:gravity="left"/>

    <ListView
            android:layout_height="0dp"               
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    <Button              
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to avoid to further nest the layout with additional LinearLayouts, unless there is no other way.

Comment: consider using relative layout for efficiency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (not tested):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    <ListView
            android:layout_height="0dp"                
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>

    <ListView
            android:layout_height="0dp"               
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    <Button              
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your button needs to have `wrap_content` height and (I think the reason of your bug) `LinearLayout` should have `fill_parent` as the height.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the `fill_parent` part, that solved my problem. For future readers, this works for `horizontal` `LinearLayout` as well as the `vertical` posted here.